# add_menu_page wordpress доступ для редактора

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Здравствуйте.

Кто в курсе, есть ли возможность создать админ меню в админ панели, в файле function.php, где доступ будет только для редакторов и админов? Просто я смотрю разные фрэймворки, доступ к которым доступен и админам и редакторам. Там это как-то реализовано..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот](https://misha.blog/wordpress/option-pages.html) отличная статья, где всё подробно и наглядно.
В частности, вам нужен параметр `$capability`, смотреть [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_menu_page)